# IE 8/9 ClearType problem

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, cleartype

I installed IE9, but it is impossible to turn off ClearType. So I removed IE9, and now in my IE8 I can't turn off ClearType, because checkbox is always disable: [image]

Please help, what can I do?

Comment: I think you need to be logged in as Admin to do those changes.

Answer (score 2):

If you are logged in as an Admin user and the option is still greyed out you could try amending this registry key manually:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\UseClearType REG_SZ no

I'm going to try to 'fix' IE9 for now but it's such a shame that MS insist on ClearType and are slowly removing any user preferences to change it...